# Synchronize two threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm currently learning concurrent programming. I have two threads and I want them to act like this:

- the first thread runs N times while the second one waits
- when the first one is done, the second does its job and the first waits
- when the second thread is done, repeat.

I'm trying to do it in C using `pthread` library. Here's some pseudocode (hopefully understandable)

```
int cnt = 0;

void* thread1(){
   while(1){
     // thread 1 code
     
     cnt ++;
     if(cnt == N){
        let_thread2_work();
        wait_thread2();
     }
   }
}


void* thread2(){
  while(1){
    wait_thread1();
  
    // thread2 code

    cnt = 0;
    let_thread1_work();
   }
}
```

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Please don't use threads this way. It's not a logical way to use threads and kind of defeats the entire point of using threads. If you're learning, you really should learn the right way first.

Comment: In particular, it *never* makes sense to wait for a thread except when shutting something down. It does make sense for some particular work to be done or result to be ready.

Comment: Google "pthread synchronization" and read about mutexes and semaphores.

Comment: what if the first thread produces some data and the second one processes it, but working on the same data structure (so that I can't let the first one keep producing) ?

Comment: If the two threads never run concurrently, they have no reason to exist as two separate threads. A single-threaded program that does the two tasks alternately will produce the same result without the whole hassle.

Comment: @jay Then you need to wait for the data to be produced. You aren't waiting for a thread, you are waiting for some data. This slight change in thinking is critical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like David Schwartz commented, this doesn't make a ton of sense with just thread1 and thread2 waiting on each other, not actually doing any work in parallel. But maybe eventually you want multiple "thread1"s, all processing jobs at the same time until they finish a batch of N jobs, then they all stop and wait for "thread2" to do some kind of post-processing before the pool of worker threads start back up.

In this situation I would consider using a couple [condition variables](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h032r/index.html), one for your worker threads to communicate to your post-processing thread that they're waiting, and one for your post-processing thread to tell the workers to start working again. You can declare a condition variable and a helper mutex in the global scope right next to your "cnt" variable, which I'm calling "jobs_done" for clarity:

```
#include<pthread.h>

#DEFINE NUM_WORKERS 1 // although it doesn't make sense to just have 1
#DEFINE BATCH_SIZE 50 // this is "N"

// we're going to keep track of how many jobs we have done in
// this variable
int jobs_done = 0;

// when a worker thread checks jobs_done and it's N or greater,
// that means we have to wait for the post-processing thread to set
// jobs_done back to 0. so the worker threads "wait" on the
// condition variable, and the post-processing thread "broadcasts"
// to the condition variable to wake them all up again once it's
// done its work
pthread_cond_t jobs_ready_cv;

// we're going to use this helper mutex. whenever any thread
// reads or writes to the jobs_done variable, we have to lock this
// mutex. that includes the worker threads when they check to see if
// they're ready to wake up again.
pthread_mutex_t jobs_mx;

// here's how the worker threads will communicate to the post-process
// thread that a batch is done. to make sure that all N jobs are fully
// complete before postprocessing happens, we'll use this variable to
// keep track of how many threads are waiting for postprocessing to finish.
int workers_done = 0;

// we'll also use a separate condition variable and separate mutex to
// communicate to the postprocess thread.
pthread_cond_t workers_done_cv;
pthread_mutex_t workers_done_mx;
```

Then in your setup code, initialize the condition variables and helper mutexes:

```
int main() { // or something
   pthread_cond_init(&jobs_ready_cv, NULL);
   pthread_mutex_init(&jobs_mx, NULL);
   pthread_cond_init(&workers_done_cv, NULL);
   pthread_mutex_init(&workers_done_mx, NULL);
  ...
}
```

So, your worker threads (or "thread1"), before taking a job, will check to see how many jobs have been taken. If N (here, BATCH_SIZE) have been taken, then it updates a variable to indicate that it has no work left to do. If it finds that all of the worker threads are done, then it signals the postprocess thread ("thread2") through `workers_done_cv`. Then, the thread waits for a signal from the postprocess thread through `

```
void* worker_thread(){
   while(1){
      /* first, we check if the batch is complete. we do this first
       * so we don't accidentally take an extra job.
       */
      pthread_mutex_lock(&jobs_mx);
      if (jobs_done == BATCH_SIZE) {

         /* if BATCH_SIZE jobs have been done, first let's increment workers_done,
          * and if all workers are done, let's notify the postprocess thread.
          * after that, we release the workers_done mutex so the postprocess
          * thread can wake up from the workers_done condition variable.
          */
         pthread_mutex_lock(&workers_done_mx);
         ++workers_done; 
         if (workers_done == NUM_WORKERS) {
            pthread_cond_broadcast(&workers_done_cv);
         }
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&workers_done_mx);

         /* now we wait for the postprocess thread to do its work. this
          * unlocks the mutex. when we get the signal to start doing jobs
          * again, the mutex will relock automatically when we wake up.
          *
          * note that we use a while loop here to check the jobs_done
          * variable after we wake up. That's because sometimes threads
          * can wake up on accident even if no signal or broadcast happened,
          * so we need to make sure that the postprocess thread actually
          * reset the variable. google "spurious wakeups"
          */
         while (jobs_done == BATCH_SIZE) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&jobs_ready_cv, &jobs_mx); 
         }
      }

      /* okay, now we're ready to take a job.
       */
      ++jobs_done;
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&jobs_mx); 

      // thread 1 code 

   }
}
```

Meanwhile, your postprocess thread waits on the `workers_done_cv` immediately, and doesn't wake up until the last worker thread is done and calls `pthread_cond_broadcast(&workers_done_cv)`. Then, it does whatever it needs to, resets the counts, and broadcasts to the worker threads to wake them back up.

```
void* postprocess_thread(){
  while(1){

    /* first, we wait for our worker threads to be done
     */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&workers_done_mx);
    while (workers_done != NUM_WORKERS) {
      pthread_cond_wait(&workers_done_cv, &workers_done_mx);
    }
  
    // thread2 code

    /* reset count of stalled worker threads, release mutex */
    workers_done = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&workers_done_mx);

    /* reset number of jobs done and wake up worker threads */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&jobs_mx);
    jobs_done = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&jobs_mx);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&jobs_ready_cv);
  }
}
```

Also take heed of David Schwartz's advice that you probably don't actually need the postprocessing thread to wait on the worker threads. If you don't need this, then you can get rid of the condition variable that makes the worker threads wait for the postprocess thread, and this implementation becomes a lot simpler.

edit: mutex protected the assignment to jobs_done in postprocess_thread(), added a forgotten ampersand

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use mutex:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mutex-lock-for-linux-thread-synchronization/

Another solution, but using semaphore:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-binary-semaphore-and-mutex/?ref=rp

Or creating own lightthread schedule.
for exemple:
http://www.dunkels.com/adam/pt/   [edited]